# PHP: How to calculate time remaining between last insert time and now()

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, time

I'm using the following to restrict an IP to send 1 message per 5minutes.
So I want to echo time remaining, how do I calculate that?

Here's my PHP

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ip = '$ip' AND mtime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 echo "<script> 
           alert ('You can only send 5 message every 10min. please wait.')
       </script>";
} else {

}
```

Comment: you are not fetching the data then how can you calculate remaining time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mtime column contain [microtime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.microtime.php) value, you can do it like that:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ip = '$ip' AND mtime >= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE ORDER by mtime DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $diff = microtime(true) - $row['mtime']; //here the time difference between last sended message and this try
    $remaining = (5*60 - (int) $diff);
    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

I also change the query order in order to get difference between now and the last message. If you need later to check for 5 messages per time, you need to remove that order.

You can use time function, if microtime isn't working:

```
$diff = time() - $row['mtime'];
```

Comment: probably its not mirco time because when i echo $remailning i get this '-1385789502', is that seconds?

Comment: Yeah, this is seconds. Try just echo microtime(true). Is it working?

Comment: You can use time() instead.

Comment: @Eustatia I am glad that this was worked for you, but i will recomend you to use PDO insted of standard mysql_request, especially if you using users input data while connection to database. this is usefull link about pdo: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: i actually read on PDO, i just don't understand it, im still new in this, how is it gonna make things better or is it more secure than what i'm using now?

Answer (score 0):

get current time first like this in timestamp

```
$c_time = strtotime(date('d-M-Y g:i:s'));
```

now get time past 5 minute like this

```
$l_time = $c_time-(5*60);
```

now put your query

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE ip = '$ip' AND mtime >= '$l_time' ORDER by mtime DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $remaining_time = $c_time - $row['mtime']; // this will be remaining time in seconds use it accordingly

    ...
}
else {
    ...
}
```

i hope you will find your answer

Comment: this returns seconds as the other answer.

Comment: yes now you can change it in minutes and seconds or any time format which you require as remaining time.